# single WCF endpoint for all commands in Nservicebus

Tags: wcf, nservicebus

We are trying to build a Nservicebus service that can communicated with form and wpf based clients using WCF. I have read that you can inherit from WcfService.

like:

```
 public class ThirdPartyWebSvc : WcfService<ThirdPartyCmd, ThirdPartyCmdResponse>
```

And then you simple create a endpoint in the app.config and you done like described [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/expose-an-endpoint-as-a-web-wcf-service). but the problem is that i have to create a endpoint for every command.

I would like to have a single endpoint that excepts any command and returns its response.

```
public class ThirdPartyWebSvc : WcfService<ICommand, IMessage>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Using Nservicebus for client communication can't be done for us and i don't want to build a proxy like server unless thats the only way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: *I would like to have a single endpoint that excepts any command and returns its response* - why do you want this?

Comment: It will be for internal use only, no external services. We are having problems with clients installing msmq. In a Nservicebus book we have read that for clients like form clients you can (better?) use wcf. Also we are dealing with a lot of legacy systems i think it would be easier to just use wcf until a new version is done.

Comment: No, I don't mean why do you want to expose your NSB endpoints as WCF services, I mean why do you want to expose your NSB endpoints over *a single* WCF service?

Comment: Sorry i misread that. Because i dont want to have multiple WCF endpoint for every NSB endpoint. Like in the example on the particular website it exposes a single NSB endpoint 'CancelOrder' but we have many NSB endpoints and many more will be added. I would like for a client to just send the command to the WCF which then sends it to Nservicebus. WCF should not care about anything and just send it to Nservicebus.

Comment: You mean polymorphically do a Bus.Send() on anything the user sends in on the request? How will the bus know which endpoint to send the message to?

Comment: Well that one of the problems i have that made me post this question. I was thinking something with a wrapper giving it the command and the type then send that to the WCF service but i don't know if that will work or is really what you want. Do you know how this is normally done? would you create a wcf endpoint for every nsb endpoint? @TomRedFern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I can gather, you want to expose a WCF service operation which consumers can call to polymorphically pass one of a number of possible commands to, and then have the service route that command to the correct NServiceBus endpoint which then handles the command.

Firstly, in order to achieve this you should forget about using the NserviceBus.WcfService base class, because to use this you must closely follow the guidance in the article you linked in your post.

Instead, you *could*:

1. design your service operation contract to accept polymorphic requests by using the [ServiceKnownType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on your operation definition, adding all possible command types,
2. host the service using a regular System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(), and then configure an NserviceBus.IBus in the startup of your hosted WCF service, and
3. define your [UnicastBusConfig](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/specify-message-destination) config section in your service config file by adding all the command types along with the recipient queue addresses

However, you now have the following drawbacks:

- Because of the requirement to be able to pass in implementations of ICommand into the service, you will need to recompile your operation contract each time you need to add a new command type.
- You will need to manage a large quantity of routing information in the config file, and if any of the recipient endpoints change, you will need to change your service config.
- If your service has availability problems then no more messages to any of your NSB endpoints.
- You will need to write code to handle what to do if you do not receive a response message from the NSB endpoints in a timely manner, and this logic may depend on the type of command sent.

I hope you are beginning to see how centralizing this functionality is not a great idea.

All the above problems would go away if you could get your clients to send commands to the bus in the standard way, but without msmq how can you do that?

Well, for a start you could look at using one of the [other supported transports](http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/multi-transport-support).

If none of these work for you and you have to use WCF hosted services, then you must follow the guidance in the [linked article](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/expose-an-endpoint-as-a-web-wcf-service). This guidance is there to steer you in the correct direction - multiple WCF services sounds like a pain, until you try to centralize them into a single service - then the pain gets bigger, not less.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer and taking the time to understand, wish i could give you more points for that. I'll have a look at our design again with the po. Thanks